# drawLayer в jCanvas

Tags: jquery, canvas

Есть addLayer и после него drawLayers

```
$('canvas').addLayer({
  name: 'Box',
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillStyle: '#585',
  x: 100, y: 100,
  width: 100, height: 50,
})
.drawLayers();
```

Этот код сразу рисует слой. Но если я убираю drawLayers, то слой появляется только тогда, когда я ухожу мышкой с поля, а иногда когда навожу.

```
$('canvas').addLayer({
  name: 'Box',
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillStyle: '#585',
  x: 100, y: 100,
  width: 100, height: 50,
});
```

Я так понимаю, пока я не нарисовала этот слой, а только добавила, он вообще появляться не должен.

Я хочу рисовать его потом так:  `$('canvas').drawLayer('Box');`

Как сделать так, чтобы, пока я его не нарисовала, он не появлялся?

[Пример](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=JCgnY2FudmFzJykuYWRkTGF5ZXIoewogIG5hbWU6ICdCb3gnLAogIHR5cGU6ICdyZWN0YW5nbGUnLAogIGZpbGxTdHlsZTogJyM1ODUnLAogIHg6IDEwMCwgeTogMTAwLAogIHdpZHRoOiAxMDAsIGhlaWdodDogNTAsCn0pOw==)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я все еще не поняла, почему пример работает именно так, но поняла, как сделать так, чтобы пока я не нарисовала слой, он не появлялся.

Когда добавляю слой, нужно установить параметр visible на false, затем, когда хочу его показать, нужно использовать setLayer() для установки параметра visible на true. И еще нужно drawLayer().

```
$('canvas').addLayer({
  name: 'Box',
  visible: false,
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillStyle: '#585',
  x: 100, y: 100,
  width: 100, height: 50,
});
...
$('canvas').setLayer('Box', {
  visible: true,
});
drawLayer('Box');
```